# Yesod - Aeson, "when expecting a Int64, encountered String instead"

Tags: haskell, yesod, aeson

I have the following model:

```
Conf
  productTaxRateId ProductTaxRateId Maybe
  barCodeLength Int
```

I've sent the following json to server:

```
{
  "attributes": {
    "barCodeLength":25
  },
  "relationships": {
    "productTaxRate": {
      "data": {
        "id": "1",
        "type": "ProductTaxRate"
      }
    }
  },
 "id": "1",
 "type": "Conf"
}
```

Following is my `FromJSON`:

```
instance FromJSON Conf where
  parseJSON (Object o) = Conf 
      <$> ((o .: "relationships") >>= (.: "productTaxRate") >>= (.: "data") >>= (.: "id"))
      <*> ((o .: "attributes") >>= (.: "barCodeLength"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

But I am getting the following error from my request:

```
{"message":"Invalid Arguments","errors":["when expecting a Int64, encountered String instead"]}
```

**How can I properly do the conversion?**

Thank you in advance, `Haskell` and `Yesod` are excellent.

Comment: probably `ProductTaxRateId` is an `Int64` but you're supplying `"id": "1"` instead of `"id": 1`

Comment: @mb21 Yes... but I don't want to change the json (I am following a standart), I just want to make a conversion

Comment: @FtheBuilder You can (inefficiently) parse the string using `readMaybe :: String ->Maybe Int64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a way to do this, which was quite straight forward, I've just used `fromPathPiece`!

```
instance FromJSON Conf where
  parseJSON (Object o) = Conf 
      <$> fmap fromPathPiece ((o .: "relationships") >>= (.: "productTaxRate") >>= (.: "data") >>= (.: "id"))
      <*> ((o .: "attributes") >>= (.: "barCodeLength"))
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```